# adding a new value to database, no error but does not enter

Tags: php, mysql

When a teamname is not in the database I want to enter it if not ignore it. But I do not get an error all I see is the echoed statement but it is not entered into the database.
The database is MySQL and table name is 2012FallTeamstats I have a team_id column which is autoincremented a win a loses and a percentages field. (4 total in table)

```
mysql_query("SELECT teamname FROM 2012FallTeamstats WHERE teamname = '$teamH'"); 
if (mysql_affected_rows() == 0) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO 2012FallTeamstats (teamname) VALUES ('$teamH')");
    echo "New: <strong>".stripslashes($teamH)."</strong> (home team) inserted into the database.<br>";
}
```

Comment: add errors on fail with `or die(mysql_error())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try mysql_num_rows() instead of mysql_affected_rows.

code like this.

```
$result_team =  mysql_query(.........); (your code)
```

then

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result_team) == 0)
{
//insert command
}
```

Comment: Yes this was it, just like Lawrence Cherone answer only I did not single tic the column names. Another error I encountered was that I thought I set the first column to auto-increment but I did not. Now all updates properly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you cut and paste the SQL that's printed out and enter into MySQL from the command line? I suspect that you might need to add the extra fields from the table into your SQL, but if you run the existing SQL, you'll see if there's an issue with the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your not getting the result from the query amongst other things:

**Notice:** `$result=`

Plus `mysql_num_rows()` & `quoting column` & `or die(mysql_error());`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `teamname` FROM `2012FallTeamstats` WHERE teamname = '$teamH'"); 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `2012FallTeamstats` (teamname) VALUES ('$teamH')")or die(mysql_error());
    echo "New: <strong>".stripslashes($teamH)."</strong> (home team) inserted into the database.<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second statement probably isn't being called as the mysql_affected_rows() doesn't give you the count from the select statement- that function is only for your CRUD operations. Try replacing this with mysql_num_rows()